# SMTP , they are hacking my server spammed?

Tags: iis-6, smtp, smtp-auth

```
2013-04-15 18:12:55 217.119.50.209 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 ADSERVER - 25 -    - 250-blue-ld-242.synserver.de 0 0 28 0 359 SMTP - - - -
2013-04-15 18:12:55 217.119.50.209 OutboundConnectionCommand  SMTPSVC1 ADSERVER - 25 MAIL - FROM:<ptxbgl@nrwaf.com>+SIZE=817 0 0 4 0 359 SMTP - - - -
2013-04-15 18:12:55 217.119.50.209 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 ADSERVER - 25 -    - 250+2.1.0+Ok 0 0 12 0 499 SMTP - - - -
2013-04-15 18:12:55 217.119.50.209 OutboundConnectionCommand  SMTPSVC1 ADSERVER - 25 RCPT - TO:<info@phitecs.com> 0 0 4 0 499 SMTP - - - -
2013-04-15 18:14:56 217.119.50.209 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 ADSERVER - 25 -    - 450+4.1.8+<ptxbgl@nrwaf.com>:+Sender+address+rejected:+Domain+not+found 0 0 71 0 120994 SMTP - - - -
2013-04-15 18:14:56 217.119.50.209 OutboundConnectionCommand  SMTPSVC1 ADSERVER - 25 RSET - - 0 0 4 0 120994 SMTP - - - -
2013-04-15 18:14:56 217.119.50.209 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 ADSERVER - 25 -    - 250+2.0.0+Ok 0 0 12 0 121119 SMTP - - - -
2013-04-15 18:15:00 217.119.50.204 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 ADSERVER - 25 -    - 220+blue-ld-246.synserver.de+ESMTP+SynServer 0 0 44 0 3791 SMTP - - - -
2013-04-15 18:15:00 217.119.50.204 OutboundConnectionCommand  SMTPSVC1 ADSERVER - 25 EHLO - adserver 0 0 4 0 3791 SMTP - - - -
2013-04-15 18:15:00 217.119.50.204 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 ADSERVER - 25 -    - 250-blue-ld-246.synserver.de 0 0 28 0 3916 SMTP - - - -
2013-04-15 18:15:00 217.119.50.204 OutboundConnectionCommand  SMTPSVC1 ADSERVER - 25 MAIL - FROM:<ptxbgl@nrwaf.com>+SIZE=817 0 0 4 0 3916 SMTP - - - -
2013-04-15 18:15:00 217.119.50.204 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 ADSERVER - 25 -    - 250+2.1.0+Ok 0 0 12 0 4041 SMTP - - - -
2013-04-15 18:15:00 217.119.50.204 OutboundConnectionCommand  SMTPSVC1 ADSERVER - 25 RCPT - TO:<info@phitecs.com> 0 0 4 0 4041 SMTP - - - -
2013-04-15 18:17:00 217.119.50.204 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 ADSERVER - 25 -    - 450+4.1.8+<ptxbgl@nrwaf.com>:+Sender+address+rejected:+Domain+not+found 0 0 71 0 124317 SMTP - - - -
2013-04-15 18:17:00 217.119.50.204 OutboundConnectionCommand  SMTPSVC1 ADSERVER - 25 RSET - - 0 0 4 0 124317 SMTP - - - -
2013-04-15 18:17:00 217.119.50.204 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 ADSERVER - 25 -    - 250+2.0.0+Ok 0 0 12 0 124442 SMTP - - - -
2013-04-15 18:17:00 217.119.50.249 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 ADSERVER - 25 -    - 220+blue-ld-241.synserver.de+ESMTP+SynServer 0 0 44 0 125 SMTP - - - -
2013-04-15 18:17:00 217.119.50.249 OutboundConnectionCommand  SMTPSVC1 ADSERVER - 25 EHLO - adserver 0 0 4 0 125 SMTP - - - -
2013-04-15 18:17:00 217.119.50.249 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 ADSERVER - 25 -    - 250-blue-ld-241.synserver.de 0 0 28 0 250 SMTP - - - -
2013-04-15 18:17:00 217.119.50.249 OutboundConnectionCommand  SMTPSVC1 ADSERVER - 25 MAIL - FROM:<ptxbgl@nrwaf.com>+SIZE=817 0 0 4 0 250 SMTP - - - -
2013-04-15 18:17:00 217.119.50.249 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 ADSERVER - 25 -    - 250+2.1.0+Ok 0 0 12 0 374 SMTP - - - -
2013-04-15 18:17:00 217.119.50.249 OutboundConnectionCommand  SMTPSVC1 ADSERVER - 25 RCPT - TO:<info@phitecs.com> 0 0 4 0 374 SMTP - - - -
```

How to input login whit password? Server refuse my connections now but this continue spam my server log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are trying to exploit a bad configuration and not getting the message to stop trying when they find it (those are the 450 status messages). This is normal background hacking, and it is being handled correctly.

Comment: Oh thanks but was late my new configs, I changed the port a alot of others things but the gmail already banned my ip. I miss the times when my mails recieved on mailbox. thanks.

Comment: And about some 250-rmail-378.daum.net+Hello+[199.168.187.217],+pleased+to+meet+you 0 0 67 0 405 SMTP <br> messages
Do you can give a brief about it?